# Has no method scrollTo

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, scrollto

I am trying to call the scrollTo method in a backbone.js event function. I want to scroll to a certain div tag when a list anchor is clicked. I binded the click event to a function and called the scrollTo method in that function, but I get the error, "**Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)} has no method 'scrollTo'**" when I click the anchor.

Please help!

Here are some sample code.

```
var MenuItemListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#menuitem_list_container'),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render: function() {
        var template = _.template( $("#menuitem_list_template").html(), {selectedindex: menuItemList.get('selectedindex'), menuitemlist: menuItemList.get('menuitemlist')});
        this.el.html(template);
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        "click .nav a":"buttonClick"
    },
    buttonClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        target = e.currentTarget.hash;
        alert(target);
        $.scrollTo(target, 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: are u sure u inlcuded scroll to library ?

Comment: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Answer (score 2):

as far as I can tell what you're doing here is use the scrollTo plugin wrongly. `e.currentTarget.hash` will be a string, the allowed parameters for the scrollTo plugin are:

- Relative selector `$(...).scrollTo( 'li:eq(14)', 800 );`
- jQuery object `$(...).scrollTo( $('div li:eq(14)'), 800 );`
- DOM Element `$(...).scrollTo( $('ul').get(2).childNodes[20], 800 );`
- Absolute number `$(...).scrollTo( 150, 800 );`
- Absolute number(hash) `$(...).scrollTo( { top:800, left:700}, 800 );`
- Absolute position `$(...).scrollTo( '520px', 800 );`
- Absolute position(hash) `$(...).scrollTo( {top:'110px', left:'290px'}, 800 );`
- Relative position `$(...).scrollTo( '+=100px', 800 );`
- Relative position(hash) `$(...).scrollTo( {top:'-=100px', left:'+=100'}, 800 );`
- Percentage `$(...).scrollTo( '50%', 800 );`

so what you want to end up doing instead, is find the position of the anchor you're trying to hit

These are the anchors that your Backbone view will end up binding an event to:

```
<div class="nav">
  <a href="#foo">Foo</a>
  <a href="#bar">Bar</a>
</div>
```

These are the targets that you're trying to hit:

```
<a name="foo">Foo</a>
<a name="bar">Bar</a>
```

so you have to try and find the location of said named anchors as such:

```
var hash = e.currentTarget.hash.replace('#', '');
var $anchor = $('a[name=' + hash + ']');
```

and then you can use the jQuery object parameter such as follows:

```
$.scrollTo( $anchor, 800 );
```

and that should solve your problem